# C++ test with classes

Tags: c++, class

Im trying to solve a problem in C++ but because im a begginer i dont know how to do it !
The problem is this if you can help me :) :

By using the below C++ code create the proper constructor functions about the classes "car" & "truck". Each function must pass the appropriate arguments to the parent class of vehicle.Additionally, the function car should initialize the passengers  when creating an object. The truck class should initialize the loadlimit when creating an object.

The statement of objects with the car () and truck () will be as follows:

car ob(passengers, wheels, range);

truck ob(loadlimit, wheels, range);

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;  
    class vehicle{        
           int num_wheels;     
           int range;
           public:
              vehicle(int w, int r){num_wheels = w; range = r;}
              void showv(){
                  cout << "Wheels: " << num_wheels << endl;
                  cout << "Range: " << range << endl;
              }
    };

    class car : public vehicle {
           int passengers;
           public:
              void show(){ 
                    void showv();     
                    cout << "Passengers: " << passengers << endl;       
              }        
    };

    class truck : public vehicle {        
           int loadlimit;        
           public:        
              void show(){       
                   void showv();        
                   cout << "Loadlimit: " << loadlimit << endl;        
              }        
    };

    int main(){        
       car c(5, 4, 500);        
       truck t(3000, 12, 1200);        
       cout << "Car: " << endl;        
       c.show();        
       cout << "Truck: " << endl;        
       t.show();        
       return 0;        
    }
```

Comment: Where are the other data members of class "car" and "truck" those need to be initialized?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I dont know where it could be im tottally beginer and thats how the test is.. Sorry.
I suppose that the constructor functions wich the test demands will be replaced into classes  truck and vehicle .. (?)
Dont know so much to guide/help.. ima tottally noob in c++ , im trying to learn with my c knowledge :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `Car` and `Truck` does not have constructors that take required parameters and pass to the base class's constructor. they should be like this:

```
 class car : public vehicle {

  int passengers;

 public:

  car(int w,int r,int p): vehicle(w,r), passengers(p){}
  void show(){

        void showv();

        cout << "Passengers: " << passengers << endl;

  }
};

class truck : public vehicle {

       int loadlimit;

       public:

          truck(int r, int w, int l):vehicle(r,w),loadlimit(l){}

          void show(){

               void showv();

               cout << "Loadlimit: " << loadlimit << endl;

          }

};
```

Comment: @user3610727 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider 
[accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. 
This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some
reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Base member initialisation

`Car` Constructor:

```
car(int a, int b, int c) : vehicle(a,b),passengers(c){};   //initialiser list
```

`Truck` Constructor:

```
 truck(int g, int h, int j):vehicle(g,h),loadlimit(j){}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Contractor to **car** and **truck**

```
class car : public vehicle {

          int passengers;
          public:
            car(int p) : vehicle(int w, int r)    // Call the superclass constructor in the subclass' 
             {
                passengers = p;
             }

            void show()
             { 
               showv();     
               cout << "Passengers: " << passengers << endl;       
             }        
        };
```

The same thing for Truck

Answer (score -1):

Simple Solution,

```
car::car(int w,int r,int p)
{
    passengers = p;
    vehicle::vehicle(w,r);
}
```

Comment: calling `vehicle::vehicle(w,r)` will *try to* create a temporary, not initialize base part, but will fail as `vehicle` does not have default constructor.

Comment: @Rakibul, the class itself shows the definition of vechicle(w,r)

Comment: It should get `no appropriate default constructor error`, since `car::car` does not pass base constructor arguments.